# Как после поворота экрана узнать какой фрагмент был последний в frameLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть два фрагмента и FrameLayout, причем я делаю по нажатию на кнопку из первого фрагмента переход на второй. Мне нужно после поворота экрана узнать какой фрагмент был перед поворотом в FrameLayout и сделать replace его. Какой в данном случае будет лучший способ это реализовать?

Comment: Исходя из описания, ваш подход уже не самый лучший и решение будет уже не самое лучшее, а информации не достаточно что бы подказать направление. Вам чтобы знать какой был открыт последний фрагмент можно например хранить его в поле активити по TAG или ID

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что лучше использовать <fragment>? Если да, расскажите такое решение. Для лучшего понимания зачем мне фрагменты, а не допустим активити: в версии для телефона, я нажимаю на кнопку на toolbar и перехожу во второй фрагмент, и со второго нажимаю на кнопку на toolbar   и перехожу в первый. В планшетной версии второй фрагмент не будет скрываться справа, ну и соответственно все кнопки и анимации пропадут.

Answer (score 0):

В общем пока что решил так:

```
val GALLERY_KEY = "gallery is showing"
private var gallery = true
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    gallery = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean(GALLERY_KEY) ?: true
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, if (gallery) GalleryFragment() else URLsFragment())
        .commit()
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putBoolean(GALLERY_KEY, supportFragmentManager.fragments[0] is GalleryFragment)
}
```